# Why can't mwifiex_sdio find firmware? (Arch Linux ARM on an xe303c12 chromebook)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, chromebook

I decided to install Arch Linux on my XE303C12 ARM-based Samsung chromebook after getting sick of dual booting chrubuntu/chromeos. I followed the instructions here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Samsung_Chromebook_%28ARM%29

I successfully flashed a non-verified u-boot to the SPI flash and replaced everything on the internal SSD with the arch linux kernel and rootfs obtained from archlinuxarm.org as per the instructions here:
http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/samsung/samsung-chromebook#qt-platform_tabs-ui-tabs2

After playing around with the u-boot prompt, my system boots successfully into arch linux on the SSD.
However, I can no longer establish a wifi connection.

```
ip link show
```

lists only "lo"; mlan0 has not been created.

Here is part of the output of dmesg (character limit won't let me post the whole thing):

```
[    1.607858] exynos-mdev.0: Media0[0xed90f400] was registered successfully
[    1.609608] exynos-mdev.1: Media1[0xed90f800] was registered successfully
[    1.611336] exynos-mdev.2: Media2[0xed90fc00] was registered successfully
[    1.613231] ntc-thermistor ncp15wb473.0: Thermistor ncp15wb473:0 (type: ncp15wb473/0) successfully probed.
[    1.614968] ntc-thermistor ncp15wb473.1: Thermistor ncp15wb473:1 (type: ncp15wb473/0) successfully probed.
[    1.616682] ntc-thermistor ncp15wb473.2: Thermistor ncp15wb473:2 (type: ncp15wb473/0) successfully probed.
[    1.618371] ntc-thermistor ncp15wb473.3: Thermistor ncp15wb473:3 (type: ncp15wb473/0) successfully probed.
[    1.620387] Exynos: Kernel Thermal management registered
[    1.622023] s3c2410_wdt: S3C2410 Watchdog Timer, (c) 2004 Simtec Electronics
[    1.623837] s3c2410-wdt 101d0000.watchdog: watchdog inactive, reset disabled, irq disabled
[    1.625756] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    1.627601] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.22.0-ioctl (2011-10-19) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    1.629409] device-mapper: verity-chromeos: dm-verity-chromeos registered
[    1.631129] device-mapper: bootcache: version 0.1.0 loaded
[    1.632892] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    1.634605] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    1.636229] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.637907] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    1.639546] Synopsys Designware Multimedia Card Interface Driver
[    1.639711] dw_mmc dw_mmc.0: Using internal DMA controller.
[    1.643026] dw_mmc dw_mmc.0: Version ID is 241a
[    1.644765] dw_mmc dw_mmc.0: DW MMC controller at irq 107, 32 bit host data width, 128 deep fifo
[    1.646609] dw_mmc dw_mmc.0: wp gpio not available
[    1.646669] mmc0: no vmmc regulator found
[    1.647488] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 2 using s5p-ehci
[    1.650172] s5p-ehci s5p-ehci: s5p_hub_control:70 resetting HSIC port phys DONE
[    1.654423] dw_mmc dw_mmc.2: Using internal DMA controller.
[    1.656088] dw_mmc dw_mmc.2: Version ID is 241a
[    1.657870] dw_mmc dw_mmc.2: DW MMC controller at irq 109, 32 bit host data width, 128 deep fifo
[    1.659670] mmc1: no vmmc regulator found
[    1.662559] dw_mmc dw_mmc.3: Using internal DMA controller.
[    1.664312] dw_mmc dw_mmc.3: Version ID is 241a
[    1.666132] dw_mmc dw_mmc.3: DW MMC controller at irq 110, 32 bit host data width, 128 deep fifo
[    1.668001] dw_mmc dw_mmc.3: wp gpio not available
[    1.668047] dw_mmc dw_mmc.3: cd gpio not available
[    1.669773] mmc2: no vmmc regulator found
[    1.674320] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.676002] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.679362] max98095 7-0011: Failed to reset DSP: -6
[    1.681294] max98095 7-0011: Failure reading hardware revision: -1
[    1.683017] max98095 7-0011: asoc: failed to probe CODEC max98095.7-0011: -1
[    1.684736] mmc_host mmc0: Bus speed (slot 0) = 100000000Hz (slot req 784314Hz, actual 781250HZ div = 64)
[    1.686522] asoc: failed to instantiate card DAISY-I2S: -1
[    1.688404] Netfilter messages via NETLINK v0.30.
[    1.691202] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (16384 buckets, 65536 max)
[    1.695446] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[    1.697279] arp_tables: (C) 2002 David S. Miller
[    1.699080] TCP: cubic registered
[    1.701034] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    1.703174] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.706215] sctp: Hash tables configured (established 43690 bind 52428)
[    1.708191] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 4 part 30 variant f rev 0
[    1.709989] ThumbEE CPU extension supported.
[    1.711809] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    1.714729] s5p-mfc s5p-mfc-v6: start latency exceeded, new value 1000 ns
[    1.716547] s5p-mfc s5p-mfc-v6: state save latency exceeded, new value 11458 ns
[    1.718360] s5p-mfc s5p-mfc-v6: stop latency exceeded, new value 625 ns
[    1.720129] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.4: start latency exceeded, new value 875 ns
[    1.721893] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.4: state save latency exceeded, new value 3833 ns
[    1.723665] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.4: stop latency exceeded, new value 584 ns
[    1.727513] VDD_INT Voltage table set with 7 Group
[    1.729251] VDD_MIF Voltage table set with 0 Group
[    1.731139] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.3: start latency exceeded, new value 1500 ns
[    1.732930] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.3: state save latency exceeded, new value 4250 ns
[    1.734697] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.3: stop latency exceeded, new value 583 ns
[    1.736522] exynos-gsc exynos-gsc.3: start latency exceeded, new value 1375 ns
[    1.738306] exynos-gsc exynos-gsc.3: state save latency exceeded, new value 2791 ns
[    1.740067] exynos-gsc exynos-gsc.3: stop latency exceeded, new value 625 ns
[    1.741821] exynos-gsc exynos-gsc.2: start latency exceeded, new value 792 ns
[    1.743584] exynos-gsc exynos-gsc.2: state save latency exceeded, new value 2541 ns
[    1.745324] exynos-gsc exynos-gsc.2: stop latency exceeded, new value 625 ns
[    1.747129] exynos-gsc exynos-gsc.1: start latency exceeded, new value 875 ns
[    1.748881] exynos-gsc exynos-gsc.1: state save latency exceeded, new value 2583 ns
[    1.750605] exynos-gsc exynos-gsc.1: stop latency exceeded, new value 583 ns
[    1.752348] registered taskstats version 1
[    1.754111] exynos-gsc exynos-gsc.0: start latency exceeded, new value 875 ns
[    1.755828] exynos-gsc exynos-gsc.0: state save latency exceeded, new value 2542 ns
[    1.757555] exynos-gsc exynos-gsc.0: stop latency exceeded, new value 625 ns
[    1.759265] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.26: start latency exceeded, new value 833 ns
[    1.760994] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.26: state save latency exceeded, new value 5916 ns
[    1.762726] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.26: stop latency exceeded, new value 583 ns
[    1.764417] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.25: start latency exceeded, new value 791 ns
[    1.766140] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.25: state save latency exceeded, new value 5916 ns
[    1.767899] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.25: stop latency exceeded, new value 584 ns
[    1.769629] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.24: start latency exceeded, new value 1292 ns
[    1.771355] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.24: state save latency exceeded, new value 5459 ns
[    1.773104] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.24: stop latency exceeded, new value 1125 ns
[    1.773114] enp32khz: incomplete constraints, leaving on
[    1.774838] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.23: start latency exceeded, new value 750 ns
[    1.778292] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.23: state save latency exceeded, new value 11625 ns
[    1.780018] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.23: stop latency exceeded, new value 708 ns
[    1.780039] en32khz_cp: incomplete constraints, leaving on
[    1.781817] en32khz_ap: incomplete constraints, leaving on
[    1.785164] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=3503
[    1.786831] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.788648] vdd_int: incomplete constraints, leaving on
[    1.790439] hub 1-2:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.790535] vdd_arm: incomplete constraints, leaving on
[    1.791013] gpio_set_debounce: gpio-165 status -22
[    1.791038] gpio_set_debounce: gpio-185 status -22
[    1.791109] mmc_host mmc0: Bus speed (slot 0) = 100000000Hz (slot req 52000000Hz, actual 50000000HZ div = 1)
[    1.791788] input: gpio-keys.7 as /devices/gpio-keys.7/input/input2
[    1.792740] mmc0: new high speed DDR MMC card at address 0001
[    1.793042] mmcblk0: mmc0:0001 SEM16G 14.6 GiB 
[    1.793171] mmcblk0boot0: mmc0:0001 SEM16G partition 1 2.00 MiB
[    1.793294] mmcblk0boot1: mmc0:0001 SEM16G partition 2 2.00 MiB
[    1.793479] hub 1-2:1.0: 3 ports detected
[    1.802590] cyapa: LID device: 'gpio-keys.7' connected
[    1.808099]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    1.812604]  mmcblk0boot1: unknown partition table
[    1.815608]  mmcblk0boot0: unknown partition table
[    1.827830] rtc-max77686 max77686-rtc: setting system clock to 2014-11-28 03:21:35 UTC (1417144895)
[    1.829538] VDD_ARM : L0, 1200000 uV
[    1.831224] VDD_ARM : L1, 1162500 uV
[    1.832911] VDD_ARM : L2, 1112500 uV
[    1.834545] VDD_ARM : L3, 1075000 uV
[    1.836153] VDD_ARM : L4, 1050000 uV
[    1.837754] VDD_ARM : L5, 1012500 uV
[    1.839316] VDD_ARM : L6, 987500 uV
[    1.840856] VDD_ARM : L7, 962500 uV
[    1.842372] VDD_ARM : L8, 937500 uV
[    1.843887] VDD_ARM : L9, 925000 uV
[    1.845360] VDD_ARM : L10, 900000 uV
[    1.846813] VDD_ARM : L11, 900000 uV
[    1.848245] VDD_ARM : L12, 900000 uV
[    1.849625] VDD_ARM : L13, 900000 uV
[    1.850987] VDD_ARM : L14, 900000 uV
[    1.852320] VDD_ARM : L15, 900000 uV
[    1.853666] mmc_host mmc2: Bus speed (slot 0) = 100000000Hz (slot req 784314Hz, actual 781250HZ div = 64)
[    1.855168] NOT Capping CPU0 frequency
[    1.856621] cpufreq_interactive: monitoring input on chromeos-ec-i2c
[    1.859051] cpufreq_interactive: monitoring input on Cypress APA Trackpad (cyapa)
[    1.862486] ALSA device list:
[    1.863873]   No soundcards found.
[    1.871006] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    1.872490] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) on device 179:2.
[    1.874820] devtmpfs: mounted
[    1.876421] Freeing init memory: 288K
[    1.882183] mmc_host mmc2: Bus speed (slot 0) = 100000000Hz (slot req 50000000Hz, actual 50000000HZ div = 1)
[    1.888002] mmc2: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[    2.077677] usb 1-2.2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using s5p-ehci
[    2.168816] systemd[1]: systemd 217 running in system mode. (+PAM -AUDIT -SELINUX -IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK -SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID -ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN )
[    2.195639] systemd[1]: Detected architecture 'arm'.
[    2.215721] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'autofs4'
[    2.218120] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <alarm>.
[    2.261983] usb 1-2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=2232, idProduct=1037
[    2.263572] usb 1-2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[    2.265090] usb 1-2.2: Product: WebCam SC-03FFM12339N
[    2.266588] usb 1-2.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[    2.268132] usb 1-2.2: SerialNumber: 200901010001
[    2.375968] systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency job for unit display-manager.service, ignoring: Unit display-manager.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
[    2.379217] systemd[1]: Starting Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    2.381051] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    2.382783] systemd[1]: Starting Remote File Systems.
[    2.386682] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
[    2.388427] systemd[1]: Starting Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    2.392599] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    2.394462] systemd[1]: Starting Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
[    2.396432] systemd[1]: Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
[    2.398373] systemd[1]: Starting Paths.
[    2.402638] systemd[1]: Reached target Paths.
[    2.404588] systemd[1]: Starting Encrypted Volumes.
[    2.408968] systemd[1]: Reached target Encrypted Volumes.
[    2.410995] systemd[1]: Starting Swap.
[    2.415525] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[    2.417635] systemd[1]: Starting Root Slice.
[    2.440477] systemd[1]: Created slice Root Slice.
[    2.442547] systemd[1]: Starting User and Session Slice.
[    2.447764] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[    2.449806] systemd[1]: Starting Device-mapper event daemon FIFOs.
[    2.454437] systemd[1]: Listening on Device-mapper event daemon FIFOs.
[    2.456484] systemd[1]: Starting /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    2.461419] systemd[1]: Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    2.463501] systemd[1]: Starting Delayed Shutdown Socket.
[    2.468030] systemd[1]: Listening on Delayed Shutdown Socket.
[    2.469992] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    2.474273] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    2.476189] systemd[1]: Starting udev Control Socket.
[    2.480522] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[    2.482484] systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Socket.
[    2.486794] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[    2.488746] systemd[1]: Starting LVM2 metadata daemon socket.
[    2.493100] systemd[1]: Listening on LVM2 metadata daemon socket.
[    2.495079] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Socket.
[    2.499305] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[    2.501174] systemd[1]: Starting System Slice.
[    2.505969] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[    2.507813] systemd[1]: Starting system-getty.slice.
[    2.512563] systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice.
[    2.515561] systemd[1]: Started Load Kernel Modules.
[    2.517298] systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
[    2.538637] systemd[1]: Started Set Up Additional Binary Formats.
[    2.540539] systemd[1]: Mounted Configuration File System.
[    2.542389] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel...
[    2.597844] systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
[    2.647828] systemd[1]: Starting Setup Virtual Console...
[    2.692909] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[    2.752802] systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
[    2.756466] systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[    2.760106] systemd[1]: Mounting Debug File System...
[    2.802760] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[    2.862961] systemd[1]: Starting Slices.
[    2.871376] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[    2.874693] systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
[    2.927903] systemd[1]: Mounting Temporary Directory...
[    2.986596] systemd[1]: Mounted Debug File System.
[    2.990647] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[    3.139951] systemd[1]: Started Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel.
[    3.179860] systemd[1]: Started Apply Kernel Variables.
[    3.224836] systemd[1]: Started Setup Virtual Console.
[    3.289819] systemd[1]: Started Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[    3.294353] systemd[1]: Mounted Temporary Directory.
[    3.352266] systemd[1]: Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
[    3.362806] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[    3.767678] systemd-journald[121]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    3.955174] s3c-rtc 101e0000.rtc: rtc disabled, re-enabling
[    3.957272] s3c-rtc 101e0000.rtc: rtc core: registered s3c as rtc1
[    4.092868] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[    4.094773] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[    4.096184] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[    4.096606] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.100348] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.102338] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.104439] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.136034] industrialio: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.140745] Bluetooth: vendor=0x2df, device=0x912a, class=255, fn=2
[    4.150380] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device WebCam SC-03FFM12339N (2232:1037)
[    4.153883] isl29018: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.160270] s5p-mfc s5p-mfc-v6: state restore latency exceeded, new value 1458 ns
[    4.162314] s5p-mfc s5p-mfc-v6: stop latency exceeded, new value 833 ns
[    4.164524] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.4: state restore latency exceeded, new value 8000 ns
[    4.166543] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.4: stop latency exceeded, new value 708 ns
[    4.168971] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.3: state restore latency exceeded, new value 6667 ns
[    4.171019] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.3: stop latency exceeded, new value 709 ns
[    4.173651] input: WebCam SC-03FFM12339N as /devices/s5p-ehci/usb1/1-2/1-2.2/1-2.2:1.0/input/input3
[    4.176805] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    4.178824] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[    4.286038] sbs-battery 4-000b: sbs-battery: battery gas gauge device registered
[    4.288155] i2c-core: driver [sbs-battery] using legacy suspend method
[    4.699776] netlink: 12 bytes leftover after parsing attributes.
[    4.701645] netlink: 12 bytes leftover after parsing attributes.
[    4.710445] netlink: 12 bytes leftover after parsing attributes.
[    4.949498] netlink: 12 bytes leftover after parsing attributes.
[    4.951280] netlink: 12 bytes leftover after parsing attributes.
[    4.953064] netlink: 12 bytes leftover after parsing attributes.
[   35.858710] netlink: 20 bytes leftover after parsing attributes.
[   35.861808] netlink: 20 bytes leftover after parsing attributes.
[   35.864968] netlink: 20 bytes leftover after parsing attributes.
[   64.648157] mwifiex_sdio mmc2:0001:1: Failed to get firmware mrvl/sd8797_uapsta.bin
[   64.662412] Bluetooth: request_firmware(firmware) failed, error code = -2
[   64.662928] s5p_mfc_load_firmware:92: Firmware is not present in the /lib/firmware directory nor compiled in kernel
[   64.662956] s5p-mfc s5p-mfc-v6: stop latency exceeded, new value 958 ns
[   64.662997] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.4: start latency exceeded, new value 959 ns
[   64.663013] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.4: state save latency exceeded, new value 4708 ns
[   64.663025] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.4: stop latency exceeded, new value 709 ns
[   64.663043] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.3: state save latency exceeded, new value 5208 ns
[   64.663054] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.3: stop latency exceeded, new value 750 ns
[   64.665289] Bluetooth: Failed to download firmware!
[   64.665820] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.4: state restore latency exceeded, new value 8958 ns
[   64.688390] Bluetooth: Downloading firmware failed!
[  107.212639] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using s5p-ehci
[  107.350866] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1625
[  107.360898] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  107.370961] usb 1-1: Product: DT 101 II
[  107.374259] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Kingston
[  107.377391] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 001372982955F9A186760E05
[  107.381506] scsi0 : usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[  107.392162] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  108.384887] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DT 101 II        1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  108.400442] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 3913664 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 GB/1.86 GiB)
[  108.413391] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[  108.414722] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 16 25 09 51
[  108.415261] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Incomplete mode parameter data
[  108.416597] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  108.420884] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Incomplete mode parameter data
[  108.422269] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  108.424299]  sda: sda1
[  108.428013] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Incomplete mode parameter data
[  108.429339] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  108.430615] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  117.588871] EXT4-fs (sda1): recovery complete
[  117.591537] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[  125.607903] s5p_mfc_load_firmware:92: Firmware is not present in the /lib/firmware directory nor compiled in kernel
[  125.615713] s5p-mfc s5p-mfc-v6: stop latency exceeded, new value 1250 ns
[  125.619540] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.4: stop latency exceeded, new value 792 ns
[  125.623354] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.4: state save latency exceeded, new value 4917 ns
[  125.627072] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.4: stop latency exceeded, new value 875 ns
[  125.630803] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.3: state save latency exceeded, new value 6458 ns
[  125.634707] s5p-sysmmu s5p-sysmmu.3: stop latency exceeded, new value 1000 ns
```

This looks to be the relevant section:

```
[   64.648157] mwifiex_sdio mmc2:0001:1: Failed to get firmware mrvl/sd8797_uapsta.bin
```

sd8797_uapsta.bin does in fact exist at /lib/firmware/mvrl/sd8797_uapsta.bin

I have no idea how the mwifiex_sdio driver works, and googling seems to just take me further down the rabbit hole. I'll mention that I did manage to get arch running with network connectivity in a dual-booting environment off of an sd card (using instructions from the 2nd link above), but that was before I flashed the nv_uboot to SPI flash. As I understand it the signed u-boot in SPI flash was previously loading a non-verified u-boot residing on the sd card which in turn loads the arch kernel. With the system that I set up according to the first link above, the nv_uboot in SPI flash directly loads the kernel without need of an intermediate boot loader. My best guess is that something from this intermediate stage is being skipped that shouldn't be.

Output from lsblk for good measure:

`NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda            8:0    1  1.9G  0 disk 
-sda1         8:1    1  1.9G  0 part /mnt
mmcblk0boot0 179:16   0    2M  1 disk 
mmcblk0boot1 179:32   0    2M  1 disk 
mmcblk0      179:0    0 14.7G  0 disk 
|-mmcblk0p1  179:1    0   16M  0 part 
-mmcblk0p2  179:2    0 14.7G  0 part /`

mmcblk0p1 contains the arch kernel

mmcblk0p2 is the rootfs

So does anyone have any suggestions for debugging this system? How can I make sure that mwifiex_sdio finds its firmware?

Sorry if I'm not being verbose enough, it's my first time posting here. Let me know if you need to see any more outputs, I'll post them.

Comment: While I grant you that this question could extend into the realm of being [On Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), it currently is not. Unless you rework it to be about specific problems encountered during the task of debugging the kernel, this question belongs on [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Comment: http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/commit/?id=a707c25a6e992b8ee6127a6ebab63dd063043047

Answer (score 2):

It is a problem with systemd. The kernel is now responsible for loading firmware, but Arch Linux Arm is still stuck on kernel 3.4 which isn't capable of loading firmware, yet after upgrading systemd it can't upgrade the firmware either.

Add systemd systemd-sysvcompat and libsystemd to IgnorePackages in /etc/pacman.conf and reinstall systemd-216 from rollback.

http://rollback.archlinuxarm.org

Comment: Thanks, I figured out that the problem was introduced by a system upgrade and so far have fixed it by reverting to out-of-box state and avoiding the systemd upgrade.

Comment: I'm at it again. Everything seems to be working except for the sound. It seems the 3.4.0 kernel does not fully support the samsung chromebook hardware. I've tried compiling a 3.8.11 kernel from source using these instructions: http://elatov.github.io/2014/11/install-chromeos-kernel-38-on-samsung-chromebook/ , but it still doesn't play well. Wifi & sound don't work. Any pointers?